# WMI Query to get Microsoft HyperV VM Domain

Tags: powershell, wmi-query

Is there a WMI query that provides the Domain of a VM deployed on a Microsoft Hypervisor? Also, we will be querying the Hypervisor for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
(get-wmiobject -class Win32_ComputerSystem).domain
```

will give you the domain information. Further information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx

You could also try:

```
get-wmiobject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select-object Name,Domain,DomainRole
```

This will tell you the type of server also.
Standalone Workstation (0)
Member Workstation (1)
Standalone Server (2)
Member Server (3)
Backup Domain Controller (4)
Primary Domain Controller (5)

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/benp/2008/08/11/scripting-hyper-v-with-wmi-and-powershell-part-1-introduction-querying-state/ has further information on HyperV.

HyperV WMI provider is located here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136992(VS.85).aspx

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.